# Dodge focus on a form upon click

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I made a simple utility application for switching between multiple instances of a game that runs in fake fullscreen or borderless window mode. Essentially it just displays a row of buttons with names for the different instances and when I click the button it switches to that instance.

Things work great except for a little annoyance - upon clicking, there is like 1 millisecond where the taskbar flashes to the foreground. I think this is due to my application getting focus for a brief moment before it hands it off to the game instance which hides the taskbar.

Is there a way to avoid getting focus on my application when clicking its buttons? Its form sits on top of all other windows at all times anyway.

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890) useful.  I was building an on-screen keyboard and so wanted to be able to click a button without taking focus.  Different goal but same principle as you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeap, adding the overrides for unselectable form did the trick